# Swift flatMap Error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, combine

```
func httpLoginSignal() ->  AnyPublisher<NetResponse<OauthToken>, Error>{
        return API.shared.combine_loadModelResource(GetOauthTokenAPI(ccCode: "86", phone: "332134", authType: "password",password: "123456a"), type: OauthToken.self)

    }

func mqttLoginSignal(accessToken: String) ->  AnyPublisher<NetResponse<MQTTToken>, Error>{
       return API.shared.combine_loadModelResource(GetMQTTTokenAPI(accessToken: accessToken), type: MQTTToken.self)

    }
```

When I use it ,it notice Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

```
 httpLoginSignal().flatMap {
            return mqttLoginSignal(accessToken: $0.data?.access_token!)
        }
```

Comment: In Combine it's highly recommended to specify the return type rather than using the shorthand ($0) syntax. In case of a type mismatch (or an ambiguous type) it gives you more information about the mistake.

Comment: @vadian write like this?    It has the same error.                   

```
httpLoginSignal().flatMap { netResponse  in
       return mqttLoginSignal(accessToken: netResponse.data?.access_token!)
}
```

Comment: You should use `.flatMap { netResponse -> TheReturnType in mqttLoginSignal(/* the rest */) }`